# Trying to add active class to menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've spent 2 hours trying to create an active menu with no success, so I figured I would ask for help. I have an html menu, some js & css...

```js
$(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
    .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $("#index li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
.active { font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='index'>
  <div class='container'>

    <div class='top'>
      <h1><a href='/' title='The Maths Project'>The Maths Project</a></h1>
    </div>
    <ul class='section active_section' id='section_2'>
      <li><span id='section_title_2' class='section_title'><a href='#' id='section_link_2'>Against the odds.</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li id='exhibit_106' class='exhibit_title'><a href="../against-the-odds/introduction"> &rarr; Introduction</a>
          </li>
          <li id='exhibit_83' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/deriving-functions'> &rarr; Deriving functions</a>
          </li>
          <li id='exhibit_83' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/exploiting-odds'> &rarr; Exploiting odds</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='section' id='section_3'>
      <li><span id='section_title_3' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_3'>Remembering everything.</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li id='exhibit_104' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/black-swans'>black swans</a>
          </li>
          <li id='exhibit_72' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/in-here-it-is-yesterday'>in here it is yesterday </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user is on a specific page, the "a" link which they have clicked should become bold. However, for whatever reason it's not working.

I would greatly appreciate any help,

Regards,

Jack

Comment: Did you tried to alert pgurl and href if you find similar values

Comment: Your `pgurl` variable will be store `introduction` when clicking on Introduction section, however your `href` you're checking in your `each` loop will be `../against-the-odds/introduction` when checking. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line gets the page name:

```
var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
                  .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

you need to apply the same logic to each of your links to see if they match:

```
$("#index li a").each(function() {

  var aurl = $(this).attr("href").substr($(this).attr("href")
                    .lastIndexOf("/")+1);

  if (aurl == pgurl || aurl == '')
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

---

Snippet below (tweaked to match as location.href won't match)

```js
$(function() {
  //var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
  //                  .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  var locationhref = "mysite.com/against-the-odds/introduction"
  var pgurl = locationhref.substr(locationhref.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
  $("#index li a").each(function() {
    var aurl = $(this).attr("href").substr($(this).attr("href")
                      .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    //console.log(aurl)
    if (aurl == pgurl || aurl == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
.active { font-weight:bold;color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='index'>
  <div class='container'>

    <div class='top'>
      <h1><a href='/' title='The Maths Project'>The Maths Project</a></h1>
    </div>
    <ul class='section active_section' id='section_2'>
      <li><span id='section_title_2' class='section_title'><a href='#' id='section_link_2'>Against the odds.</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li id='exhibit_106' class='exhibit_title'><a href="../against-the-odds/introduction"> &rarr; Introduction</a>
          </li>
          <li id='exhibit_83' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/deriving-functions'> &rarr; Deriving functions</a>
          </li>
          <li id='exhibit_83' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/exploiting-odds'> &rarr; Exploiting odds</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='section' id='section_3'>
      <li><span id='section_title_3' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_3'>Remembering everything.</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li id='exhibit_104' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/black-swans'>black swans</a>
          </li>
          <li id='exhibit_72' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/in-here-it-is-yesterday'>in here it is yesterday </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear with your question but do you want set active class to menu, so you try the below code

```js
$('#navlist a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the link from being followed
    $('#navlist a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.nav { 
    color: green;  
}
.selected { 
    color: red; 
}
.san ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<div class="san">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a class="nav" href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following and check if it works.

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $("#index li a").each(function() {
        var href = "";
        if($(this).attr("href") != '')
            href = $(this).attr("href").substr(($(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            if (href == pgurl || href  == '')
                  $(this).addClass("active");
      })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse the whole links and when any link will clicked then change the **font-weight:normal** to all links and then apply the **font-weight:bold** to currently clicked link.

```
$().ready(function () {
        $("ul>li").click(function () {
            $("ul>li").css("font-weight", "normal");
            $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
        });
    });
```